# How to install openssl to laravel 5 on linux?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, openssl

Does anyone know how to install Openssl on linux? I've done this without having any result:

1. uncomment the line of the extension in the php.ini
2. install openssl.
3. I have recompiled my php to with--with-openssl-dir = / usr/local/openssl and still nothing.

My php.info says that I'm in the version of php 5.3.10 when running the command console throws me 5.6.6 version.

I'm going crazy, thanks for your reply!

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information please. What are you trying to do that depends on OpenSSL? Are you using a shared host or is this your own development machine?

Comment: What actually happens: An error message? or no output at all?